# Cannot run Python app through Task Scheduler

Tags: python, python-3.x, scheduled-tasks

So I have a website blocker I built that blocks access to certain sites during working hours. When I run the script through Atom or the cmd, it works fine. The issues arise when I try to schedule the app to run at startup via the Task Scheduler. It doesn't start up when I turn on the computer, and I noticed that when I start the task it says 'Running' next to it, but once I close the Task Scheduler and reopen, it just says 'Ready'. Any idea on what would be causing the program to keep stopping? Apologies for the lack of detail, I'm not sure how to troubleshoot this any more than that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming you are on windows.

Go to this path in the file explorer

```
C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup
```

The startup folder in windows can be used to run anything at startup, place your program in here and it will be executed at startup. No need for scheduler :)